# VSTO Outlook : How to add a group into a build in tab?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, ms-office

I wanna ad a group on the main tab of compose mail, like in this picture.

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/4422/usentit.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/4422/usentit.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an outlook addin and Ribbon xml

Check out the article on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226712.aspx